# Конвертация NSData в NSArray

Tags: ios, swift

Перед копированием файла в iCloud пакую массив с объектами в NSData. Потом забираю файл из хранилища, приходит NSData! с таким же количеством байт как и после упаковки в дату. Пытаюсь распаковать обратно в массив. Поиск в google решение не дал.

Использую либу iCloudDocumentSync

[image: Code]
[image: Error]

Comment: судя по ошибке у вас программа ожидает `NSURL` а получает `NSString`. поставьте брекпоинт, я думаю у вас до даты даже и не доходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я уже сказал ошибка скорее всего не в конвертации, но для успокоения вот как должна проходить конвертация (если надо NSArray добавить 'NS' перед Array :) )

```
var array: Array = ["one","two"]
let data: NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(array)
array = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as! Array
print(array)
```

Comment: Я нашел проблему/ошибку. Изначально была подключена либа AutoCoding, но я ее не заюзал, и забыл за нее. Убрал, теперь другая ошибка, но уже по делу, а не бред который выдает свифт.